# @State not updating SwiftUI view when changed in mutating function and initialiser

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have tried out different ways by which @State can be updated in a SwiftUI view. There are approaches where a state change updates the related view whereas in some it does not.

### **@State change updates view**

```
@State var bodyText: String = "Hello swift"

var body: some View {
    Text(bodyText)
        .onAppear(perform: triggerTextUpdate)
}

private func triggerTextUpdate() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3) {
        bodyText = "Hello I am future swift"
    }
}
```

### **@State changes not updating the view**

**1. @State changed from initializer**

```
@State var bodyText: String = "Hello swift"
init() {
    triggerTextUpdate()
}

var body: some View {
    Text(bodyText)
}

private func triggerTextUpdate() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3) {
        bodyText = "Hello I am future swift"
    }
}
```

**2. @State changed from mutating function**

```
@State var bodyText: String = "Hello swift"
private let somePublishSubject = PublishSubject<String, Never>()
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init() {
    setUpBinding()
}

var body: some View {
    Text(bodyText)
}

mutating func setUpBinding() {
    somePublishSubject.sink { [self] text in
        self.bodyText = text
    }.store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

When the `somePublishSubject` gets invoked and alters the `bodyText` state, the view does not update.

There is not much documentation on SwiftUI which makes understanding why the view updation and `@State` changes become more confusing. Any explanation for this behaviour will be really helpful.

Comment: because your function is called before view body initialization, call your function in someView().onAppear{ } it will work perfect

Comment: @MirKaram That should not be a problem right. I think it is specific to certain cases. If you initialize the bodyText like `_bodyText = State(initialValue: "Hello Swift !")`, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) says it very clearly.

> You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body, or from methods called by it. For this reason, declare your state properties as private, to prevent clients of your view from accessing them. It is safe to mutate state properties from any thread.

it means you are not allowed to change state in your `init`, or `somePublishSubject.sink`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why is it so?

Comment: @G.Abhisek Again, as the doc says, "SwiftUI manages the storage of any property you declare as a state.", so if you change your State outside the body, it won't effect the State managed by swiftUI, your can print the state in your `mutating func setUpBinding`, your will see even if you change the value, but the printed value is still the old one.